# Crystal Report Licence Question

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, licensing

I was checking out the crystal report website and I'm wondering if I purchase it, would it be a license per machine or per user name (use it on another computer but not at the same time)? just wanted to clarify...

this is their statement

### Report Design Licensing

### SAP Crystal Reports is licensed on a named-user basis for report design.

if anyone could help me clarify this, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAP Crystal report is free to download from below link

http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/default.asp

this is the free version of Crystal report for Visual Studio 2010
Please read the comment at the bottom of the page for given link...

Comment: Hi, so what if I want to run my application on a computer that doesent have vs? I know i can develop it but to use it on a comp that doesnt have it, is it still free if i included necessary files?

Comment: Got it working with a computer without vs and cr (installed the reddist) working. Thanks